# Interaction between Binary Predictors in Multiple Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction, regression-coefficients

I have made a model with continuous and categorical(binary) predictors, with the dependent variable being continuous.

Can I create an interaction variable between 2 binary predictors and add it to the model while excluding the 2 predictors it came from?

It seems to me it would be valid in the sense that, if for example each predictor corresponds to a disease,  the interaction predictor would check for the predicting power of the simultaneous co-existence of the 2 diseases?

Would I be violating any MLR assumptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that at least one of the diseases has its own non-zero effect, by omitting that effect from the model, you now have something in the error that is mechanically correlated with an included regressor, the interaction. This violates the exogeneity assumption, and will bias the coefficient on the interaction. Thus it is good practice to include both own/main effects when adding their interaction to a model.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks a lot for this explanation! I hadn't run into the exogeneity assumption in any MLR assumptions list, I guess it is considered obvious?

Comment: @ziggy It sometimes has different names, but it is fairly standard in my experience. See the Wiki page for [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), for example.